# Möbius band inside projective plane

Tags: geometry, manifolds, projective-space, mobius-band

How can I see inside the projective plane the Möbius band?

I need to know how  the Möbius Band appears inside the projective plane.

I  know it is easy using identifications and algebraic topology.

I want to use parametrization of both the *inside and the outside* manifolds now.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Real projective plane and Möbius strip](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/342115/real-projective-plane-and-m%c3%b6bius-strip)

Comment: One possibility would be to use an immersion like the crosscap or Boy's surface, and restrict the surface's parameters so that you have something that looks like a Möbius strip.

Answer (score 0):

The Projective Line $P^1R$ is sitting inside the projective plane $$P^2R=\left\{\left[x:y:z\right]\right\}$$
as
$$P^1R=\left\{z=0\right\}$$
It is well known that $P^1R$ is homeomorphic to a circle. Now look at (edited:) some $\epsilon$-neighborhood of $P^1R$ for some positive $\epsilon$. You can check that is a nontrivial interval bundle over $P^1R$, so ist is a Möbius band.

Comment: The condition $|z|<\epsilon$ is not well defined for a point $[x:y:z]\in P^2\mathbb R$, since $[x:y:z] = [\lambda x:\lambda y:\lambda z]$ for every nonzero real number $\lambda$.

Comment: That's right, what I meant was: take a sufficiently small neighborhood of $P^1R$ (e.g. inside a chart).

Comment: In fact it suffices to take out (a small neighborhood of) $\left[0:0:1\right]$ from $P^2R$.